# Are 3 of the 4 LEDs on the Moga Pro Power Android gaming controller useless?

Tags: controllers

I don't get it. Even when it's fully charged, only the blue bottom LED is lit. When searching for BlueTooth pairing, all 4 LEDs are blinking blue, but then once it's paired, only the bottom one is lit. I thought that this is a battery power indicator because next to the top LED there are 4 dots etched in the plastic, then 3 dots for the LED below it and so on, 1 dot for the bottom LED.

I don't understand what's the point of having 4 LEDs when they could have accomplished the same functionality with 1 LED. Can't find any explanation for this in the manual.

NOTE: this is NOT about the power LED colors / meaning, etc. This concerns the *four* stacked blue LEDs' on the opposite side from the power LED.

Answer (score 1):

I thought my one was defective too, and the manual says 4 blue led when 100% charged and each one is 25% less. Googled and found this on product description: 4-way LED player indicator. I'm guessing it's used for the 4-way player indicator

Answer (score 1):

After the Moga has connected, pressing the small battery button next to the colored power LED will make those 4 blue LEDs display the battery power for a few seconds.  All four lit for 100%, 3 lit for 75%, 2 lit with the 3rd flashing for ~60%, and so forth.  It only works after the controller has paired, when still searching the button does nothing.

These also can be used as a player number indicator, as Abdullah said.  The official Android driver doesn't actually make use of this, but some third-party Moga implementations do.